# Mongo query in subdocument when keys are numeric

Tags: mongodb

I've got a mongo document structure that I can't figure out how to query into.  The challenge is that I'm trying to `find` on a sub-document whose keys are hex values but as a String.

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db['o-plan'].findOne();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b198d11794c820001ee3c1c"),
    "activities" : {
        "5b198ddba555c20001fc26e8" : [
            "5b198dc3fbfd9c0001402074"
        ],
        "5b198d8c794c820001ee3c25" : [ ],
        "5b198da4794c820001ee3c2e" : [ ],
        "5b198dc3fbfd9c0001402074" : [
            "5b198d8c794c820001ee3c25",
            "5b198da4794c820001ee3c2e"
        ]
    },
    "createdByUser" : "kfrog",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2018-06-07T19:52:49.866Z"),
    "displayId" : "OP-1",
    "displayName" : "Flux Capacitor",
    "id" : ObjectId("5b198d11794c820001ee3c1d"),
    "modifiedByUser" : "kfrog",
    "modifiedDate" : ISODate("2018-06-12T19:43:00.403Z"),
    "ownerUsername" : "kfrog",
    "releaseStatus" : "PENDING",
    "revisionId" : ObjectId("5b198def794c820001ee3c3d"),
    "version" : 1
}
```

I'm trying to find the documents whose activities sub-document contains the key '5b198ddba555c20001fc26e8' but I get no results.  How does one do this in mongo?

```
rs0:SECONDARY> db['o-plan'].find(
  {
    activities: {
      '5b198ddba555c20001fc26e8': { $exists: true }
    }
  }
).pretty();
rs0:SECONDARY>
```

Both the collection name and document schema are somewhat pathological, but that's the constraints I'm working in.  There has to be a way to query this.

How do I find within a sub-document when my keys are actually numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the dot notation:

```
db.foo.find( { 'activities.5b198ddba555c20001fc26e8': { $exists: true } } ).pretty();
```